# First item in Angular JS repeater not CSS :first-child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a series of divs in a project, in which the first one needs to be different from the others.

So I set up my css to be `item:first-child{}` as usual.

In some cases, these divs might be generated with Angular JS. I noticed when using a repeater, **ALL** the divs are first-child.

I could use my own class, as "frst" here, but I'd like to just pick up bootstrap's default.

```
<div class="media" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" ng-class="{first : $first}">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/80x80" alt="64x64" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ooomz/128.jpg" style="width: 80px;height: 80px;">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
                    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Which div are you trying to apply `first-child` to?  Can you show an example using jsfiddle or something?

Comment: I just fixed the code.  Bootstrap is looking for `.media:first-child`

Answer (score 1):

The entire block is repeated with `ng-repeat`.  You probably want to do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in iarray" class=media>
    <a class=pull-left href=#>
        ...
```

Also keep in mind that this has to the first child.  If there is:

```
<div ng-app>
    <some-non-div-tag>
    <div ng-repeat="i in iarray" class=media>
```

... it won't work either.  You would have to use `:first-of-type`

http://jsfiddle.net/27NWm/